# Error while trying to establish session with user's PIN (smartcard)

Tags: python, security, cryptography, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm using python-pkcs11 to access a smartcard I own.
Right now, I was trying to create a session, so that I could retrieve the Public Key from the card. This is the code I was testing:

```
path = (...)
os.environ["PKCS11 MODULE"] = path
lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11 MODULE'])

password = bytes("1234","utf-8")
print(password)

with token.open(user_pin=password) as session:
    print(session)
```

Everything looks good, until it reaches "user_pin=password". I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "acess.py", line 46, in <module>
    with token.open(user_pin=password) as session:
    File "pkcs11/_pkcs11.pyx", line 227, in pkcs11._pkcs11.Token.open
    AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

In the documentation, it is said that the user_password must be in bytes, and that's what I'm doing. Can somebody help me?

**Edit:**

When I test any of these 3 situations, I still get an error:

```
with token.open(user_pin='1234') as session:
    print(session)

with token.open(user_pin=b"1234") as session:
    print(session)

with token.open(user_pin="1234") as session:
    print(session)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "acess.py", line 59, in <module>
        with token.open(user_pin="1234") as session:
      File "pkcs11/_pkcs11.pyx", line 239, in pkcs11._pkcs11.Token.open
      File "pkcs11/_errors.pyx", line 88, in pkcs11._pkcs11.assertRV
        pkcs11.exceptions.UserPinNotInitialized
```

Comment: I have no idea really, but the examples I've seen on a quick glance to the docs seem to be using strings... Have you tried without casting `"1234"` to bytes (just do `token.open(user_pin='1234')` ) ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Please, take a look on the edit I made on the question

Comment: I insist: I have no idea about PKCS11 in Python, but that `UserPinNotInitialized` seems to point to... something not initialized?  Have you seen this: http://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pkcs11.lib ? It seems to be _initializing_...something?

Comment: Yes, I have already read the whole documentation. I really don't know what I am missing. Thank you for the help, anyway

Comment: Is the card and especially the PIN usable by other applications? Otherwise the PIN might be still in the state, where it needs to be defined by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the line:

**token = lib.get_token(token_label='your token Label')**

with token.open(user_pin="1234") as session:
    print(session